# International Domain Names + JQuery attr('href') problems in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, idn

I'm trying to set the href of an a element using jQuery. When I set an IDN in Firefox 6, the href is url encoded. One example is the IDN [http://räksmörgås.se](http://r%C3%A4ksm%C3%B6rg%C3%A5s.se), which is mangled to http://r%C3%A4ksm%C3%B6rg%C3%A5s.se. When I do the same in other browsers (IE8, Chrome 13, Safari 5.1), the IDN isn't encoded.

The reason I am trying to do this is that i am letting the user change hrefs and then upload a subset of the page content by ajax to a web server. I then have problems since the link is buried deep in a html string; and I'd prefer not to dig up all a elements in the html string.

Is there any way to disable the encoding of hrefs when setting it in Firefox? Or do you have any other ways I might solve the problem?

(I've noticed that if the href is a valid punycode IDN, i.e. http://www.xn--rksmrgs-5wao1o.se, the browsers are fine and dandy. But I then have to do the punycode encoding in js, something which I prefer not to; there might be one or several bugs, and there doesn't seem to be a official release of an encoder/decoder.)

The following html page displays my problem. If you input an international domain name (copy-paste "http://www.räksmörgås.se"), #linkHtml will get the entire a element, including the mangled href if using Firefox, and the correct href if using any other browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#linkText").focus();
$("#linkText").keyup(function() {
    var href = $(this).val();
    $("#link").attr('href', href);
    $("#linkHtml").text($("#link").parent().html());
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><input id="linkText" type=text /></div>
<div><a id="link" href="#">link</a></div>
<span id="linkHtml"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've seen this with TLDs that are not whitelisted by Mozilla (although .se should be ok: http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/tld-idn-policy-list.html) so maybe there is something bug-like involved? Also see: http://idn.icann.org/Firefox_Information and http://www.slideshare.net/playingwithsid/universal-acceptability

Comment: Hmm, it looks ok to me (Firefox 6 @ ubuntu) - the updated href isnt't endoded.

Comment: @WTK, are you checking the output in the span, or in Firebug? It seems as if Firebug decodes the url, so it's not possible to only check in firebug.

Comment: Btw, is this the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069187/jquery-linkify-firefox-displaying-21-instead-of-in-href-attr ? (However, the answer in that question isn't possible for this problem; I can't foresee which strange IDN:s my users are going to input.)

Comment: These IDNs were always going to be an absolute nightmare \*sigh\*

Answer (score 0):

Use decodeURI (native function) if you're concerned with how this *href* value is displayed. Following displays ok in Firefox.

```
$("#linkHtml").text(decodeURI($("#link").parent().html()));
```

Techincally, as far as I know, even while Firefox shows encoded value you should be ok with that data after submission to some server.

Comment: It's true that decodeURI in my example shows correctly. However, I'm submitting a subset of the DOM to the server (i.e. submitting $("#someDistantParentToTheLink").html()), and I'm a bit afraid that this would decode stuff that shouldn't be decoded.

Comment: So there you go, you shouldn't decode it - anything I know on a server side can handle that kind of decoding. You mentioned "and I'd prefer not to dig up all a elements in the html string." - what do you mean by that - dig up all a elements in the html - would the encoding/decoding change something in that matter?

Comment: Well, I am submitting a boatload of html to the server, and when the user uses Firefox, the href of all IDN links are encoded, but not when using any other browser. This means I have to hack around this by digging up all A tags on the server side and html decode them (yay, regex) iff the user uses Firefox.

Comment: So before you save the "boatload of html" to the database (I asssume), decode it on the server side to get rid of the problem. What kind of server-side technology are you using?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I had to do, since it seems that there's no way to make Firefox to do what I want.